# Picklist values for Master record type

Tags: page-layout, record-type, picklist

Our Salesforce org is largely vanilla, out of the box design.  We use the Standard Object Contact with no modifications.  Now we have an app that is going to use Contact in a slightly different way with just a few modifications.  There will be a new page layout (some fields removed) and a Record type for the new Contact type.  Also, we need to add a couple of new values to the picklist field Lead Source and all of this will be controlled by a new Profile (clone of Standard User).

I am not sure how I keep the new picklist values from showing up for Standard Users, though. I know how to do the opposite - it's controlled by Record Type.  So do I have to create a Record type and corresponding Page Layout to represent the default\Master state just to remove the new picklist values from the Lead Source field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will need to create a new page layout/record type if you want to give visibility to one group while hiding it from another group.

So you would have contact record type A: (original layout)
then contact Record Type B: (customized layout)

You then can assign the correct layouts by record type for the profiles you wish to view the new picklist values

Answer (score 2):

Once you've created a custom Record Type for an Object, you will no longer be able to use the -Master- RecordType, because it ceases to exist.

Therefore, you will have to create a Standard and one for this Custom App you mention.

Yes, the picklist values and the Page Layout assignment will then be controlled by the Record Types.

Comment: The Master RecordType does not go away.  It is clearly available for selection for any profile. My problem is that the default page layout now includes new picklist values that I need to hide...which I can't do without creating a new Record Type.

Comment: What I meant is you cannot assign a Custom Record Type along with the Master Record Type to a Profile, you can either allocated Master or a Custom Record Type. You can also not customise picklist values for the Master RT.